# problem on replication EFM (WAL LSN not match)

Tags: postgresql, clustering, enterprisedb

I have a postgres cluster (edb) , when i check the status i have this output :

```
Cluster Status: efm

Agent Type  Address              Agent  DB       VIP
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Master      xxxxxxxxxxxx.com UP     UP       xxxxxVIP.net*
Standby     xxxxxxxxxxxx.com UP     UP       xxxxxVIP.net

Allowed node host list:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com xx.xx.xx.xx

Membership coordinator: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com

Standby priority host list:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com

Promote Status:

DB Type     Address              WAL Received LSN   WAL Replayed LSN   Info
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Master      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com                    71A/69CD6000
Standby     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com 71A/69CD6000       71A/69CF5A80

One or more standby databases are not in sync with the master database. The following node(s) returned a WAL LSN that does not match the master: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com
```

Note the standby is not in sync withe master.  Can you help me understand why, and what I can do to fix this?

Comment: [Perhaps this Q&A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/308366/postgresql-replication-lag-without-obvious-bottleneck) provides an answer?

Comment: That doesn't make a whole lot of sense: the replayed LSN (71A/69CF5A80) is higher than the received LSN (71A/69CD6000).

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, when there is heavy load on the database, EFM doesn't show the same LSN, even though the two instances are correctly in a streaming replication mode. I understand that EFM issues the commands to get the LSNs one shortly after the other, hence the difference.
Basically when I work with such databases and I want to check if they are replicating, I issue the efm cluster-status command multiple times in short succession (think about 3 times in the span of 20 seconds): if the two LSNs continue to grow, it means that the transactions on the Primary are being replicated on the secondary; meanwhile if only one of them changes, or none of them changes (while still being different with one another) I assume there is a problem.
Hope it helps.